# iphone Scrolling of tableview with custom cells is too slow

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have this problem when deploying my application on iphone, which wasn't detected on the simulator.

this the code of the cellforrow...

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"beginning cellforRowAtIndexPath for section %d, and cell %d",[indexPath indexAtPosition:0],[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]);

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    NSString *fieldTitle;
    NSString*fieldDescription;
    [_stopWatch start];
    [PersonalSection GetField:&fieldTitle AndValue:&fieldDescription UsingIndexPath:indexPath AndPersonalInformation:_personalInfo];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewContent" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tvCell;
        self.tvCell=nil;

        ((UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]).layer.cornerRadius=11;
        ((UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2]).layer.cornerRadius=11;
    }


    UILabel*mainLabel=(UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    mainLabel.text=fieldTitle;
    //mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.745 green:0.116 blue:0.176 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel*detailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    detailLabel.text=fieldDescription;
    [_stopWatch stop];
    NSLog(@"---------End cellforRowAtIndexPath");

    return cell;
}
```

the rest is for sections and it's like return 3 or 5 no real bottleneck there.
so i'm wondering what's slowing it so much.
now the data fetching "[PersonalSection GetField:&fieldTitle..." is rather fast, it takes on the iphone maximum 0.1 ms. The problem is somewhere else, i'm guessing there's a way for optimizing this code, and i'm wondering about the custom cell influence it's only a cell with label and textfield linked to this ViewController.
Any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the main performance issue was rounding the corners of the subviews of the contentview.
using QuartzCore:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
((UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]).layer.cornerRadius=11;
```

I removed those and decreased the sizes of the controls to fit inside the cell of a sectioned table. and now they look round but the textfield and label are not.
this has fixed my scrolling performance noticeably.
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It is the same problem I have. The only way to solve this is: use an UIImageView that simulate the cornerRadius or do what you said.

Answer (score 4):

When you create the cell you're setting the identifier to @"cell" but when you dequeue it you're looking for @"MyIdentifier". It looks like you're recreating the cell every time though this.

Comment: actually i'm dequeuing using the same identifier, but yeah it's a wrong thing to do. But i've been posting the wrong code, i just updated it.