# UIView: Rounded Corners Without Performance Issues

Tags: iphone, uiview, calayer, rounded-corners, aqgridview

I am using an [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) to display my data in a grid on iPad. Every cell is a `UIView` subclass and typically, there are 18 cells displayed simultaneously.

I would like to add a round corner to these cells, so I set the `cornerRadius` property of the relevant layers (i.e. the layer of the main `UIView` and of one subview). However, this results in performance issues and the scrolling is not smooth any more. When using other `CALayer` properties, such as `shadowOpacity`, this does not happen.

Are there any other ways to add a rounded corner (apart from using an image)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I also saw a major performance hit when using cornerRadius on the layer of a view that contained a UIImageView subview.  Rasterization solved that problem:  `view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;`

Comment: you literally saved me tons of my time! :)

Comment: I have used this before with great success. However, rounding the corners on entire view causes some degradation in quality of the entire view: https://skitch.com/franklinwebber/8q8c2/ios-simulator

Comment: However, I found that the issue was the rasterization was being performed at too low of a resolution and this solved the issue `myView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`

Comment: @james Wald . i had resoled the perfomence issue using "[myview.layer setShadowPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myview.bounds].CGPath];". Shadow and corner radious is working fine in Portrait mode with smooth scrolling. but my app is supported in both mode and when i change the orientation shadow not working properly(shadow display according to fram of Portrait View) .so any idea how to resolved this ?

Comment: @Coder Perhaps you aren't setting the shadow path after the orientation change?  The the view's bounds are probably changed according to the device orientation.  You would have to set the shadow path again using the view's newly updated bounds.

Comment: @JamesWald yes exactly . i am done with this. look into it http://stackoverflow.com/a/14910451/935381 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be where you're placing the setCornerRadius call. Make sure it's somewhere that only gets called once, not, for example, in a drawRect method.

Comment: It's in the `init` method, so I guess it's not a problem.

Comment: seems to be a common problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance

Comment: I see. I am going to create an image then. Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?