# UIView shadow issue with orientation

Tags: uiview, orientation, layer, uibezierpath, dropshadow

I have `UiTableView within UiView`. I want to set `corner radius & shadow` to `UIView`.
I am using this code to give `shadow with corner`and its working fine.

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
[myView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[myView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[myView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[myView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[myView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[myView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];

// below line is for smooth scrolling
[myView.layer setShadowPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myView.bounds].CGPath];`
```

everything working fine with `Portrait mode`. My app is supported both `Orientation` and we are using `Autoresizing property` fot that. When i change the orientation `Shadow is displaying according to frame of Portrait mode`. How can this manage for both Orientation.

Any idea how to change `setShadowPath` according to Orientation OR bound ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a found the solution of my own. i have a created one method `- (void) viewWithEffects: (UIView*) myView {// copy the shadow code from the question}`. Now i called this method to `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{}` .

So when orientation change  `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` call and it will give the `Corner with Shadow effects.` Shadow will set to your view according to `Autoresize` your view. if your app not supported for both orientation than dont need to do this. Just call one on `viewdidload or viewwillAppear`. i hope it will help .

Answer (score 0):

iOS6 Rotation
Try this code and let me know if it worked for you

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
   {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   }

return YES;
}
```