# Subview isn't constrained within superview without using masksToBounds - using it results in performance issues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I was having performance issues with rounded corners, so I followed advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance) and removed the masksToBounds property, and instead of the `backgroundColor` property, used the `layer.backgroundColor` property. This works perfectly, except that I have a subview that I also want to be constrained, but its' background color isn't being masked to the rounded corners. As it doesn't fill the entire UIView, i can't have its corners be rounded.

Turning on masksToBounds results in bad performance issues.

How can I solve this?