# how to set cornerRadius of mask layer

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]

I made a view. Then I added a mask layer like this.

```
UIView *dd = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
dd.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

dd.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
dd.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0f;
[self.view addSubview:dd];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, maskRect);
[maskLayer setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
dd.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

and how can I cornerRadius on maskLayer?

I tried to

```
dd.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
dd.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0f;
```

it doesn't work. and other things too.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: @dandan78 Define "doesn't work" ??means ??

Comment: here its example of lable but as you need it for view so apply changes as needed:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance

Comment: is it the CAShapeLayer (called maskLayer) that you want to round the corners on?

Comment: Your question tags are not relevant to what you are asking.  This is not an iOS or iPhone issue

Comment: @AdamRichardson your right!!!

Answer (score 3):

Any way may be you want like this :

[image]

Add QuartzCore Framework in your Project

// Import in .m file

```
  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

// Do this code

```
 UIView *dd = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
dd.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

dd.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
dd.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[self.view addSubview:dd];

CGFloat cornerRadius = 0;
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;

UIColor *lineColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);

//drawing
CGRect frame =maskRect;

CAShapeLayer *_shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
//creating a path
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

//drawing a border around a view
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, frame.size.height - cornerRadius);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, cornerRadius);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, M_PI, -M_PI_2, NO);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, 0);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, -M_PI_2, 0, NO);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - cornerRadius);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, frame.size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, M_PI_2, NO);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, cornerRadius, frame.size.height);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, cornerRadius, frame.size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, M_PI_2, M_PI, NO);

//path is set as the _shapeLayer object's path
_shapeLayer.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);

_shapeLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
_shapeLayer.frame = frame;
_shapeLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
_shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
_shapeLayer.strokeColor = [lineColor CGColor];
_shapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;

//_shapeLayer is added as a sublayer of the view, the border is visible
[dd.layer addSublayer:_shapeLayer];
dd.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
```

May be it will work.

happy coding.

Comment: @David the above answer masks a corner radius which is what you asked in your question.  Re state your question if that is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @NiravPatel kam karu 6u .bhai.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a layer from the path as I see. Therefore, rounder corners should be already in the path to take any effect. Try using not just rect but the Bezier curves.
Create a `UIBezierPath` with cornered radius from your rect like this:

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius;
```

and use it for your layer's path