# Laggy ViewController even when not processing data

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` that does a lot of data processing up front in order to render a `UIScrollView`. The bizarre thing is, even once all the processing/rendering is done, the `UIScrollView` is very laggy when scrolling.

I've double checked that nothing is being processed, and I'm not even using the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method.

I also have a `UITableView` in the view (currently with no data) that is also laggy, so it's affecting everything in that view. (If I change tabs, none of the other views show any lag).

Could high memory usage cause this lag? It seems strange considering I remove most of the loaded data after processing. What else could it be?

**Edit**: To clarify, my `UITableView` is empty at the moment, so it's not a recycling issue. I just mentioned the `UITableView` because it's not just the `UIScrollView` that is lagging.

**Edit 2:** As @MacKentoch pointed out, using rounding can cause lag. I removed the rounding from my subviews and it fixed the issue. I was using this to round the squares to circles:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = height / 2
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is it laggy on all simulators? It happens to be laggy with iPhone 6 plus simulators (because of zoom out otherwise it would take all my screen)

Comment: Oh it's actually not super laggy on the simulator. It's more laggy on actual devices. I've come to expect it from the 6+ simulator at this point haha.

Comment: Can you run the Time Profiler instrument and post a screenshot/code for the top 5 entries?

Comment: Ok. **I'm not sure it is the same case**. But, I had same issue on a TableView when scrolling. In fact, I had some effect on multiple **subviews layers** (**shadows**, rounded...). I removed shadow effect then it was better. Shadow effects can cost too much to render on scrolling I suppose. Otherwise have you **checked** your **memory usage**?

Comment: Without code is a bit hard, are you sure you are recycling objects in cell as well?

Comment: @MacKentoch you may be on to something. My `UIScrollView` is full of subviews that are all being rounded. (It's a calendar, and each day is a colored circle). I'll try taking off rounding and see what happens. I'll also run it through the Time Profiler.

Comment: I don't believe it. @MacKentoch you were 100% right. I removed my layer modifications and it's 100% smooth. Here's the catch though, they look horrible as colored squares. Is there a more efficient way to display them as circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MacKentoch for suggesting it could be the rounded corners. After determining that was the issue, this SO answer quickly solved the problem:

[UILabel layer cornerRadius negatively impacting performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance)

Answer (score 0):

### Shadow effet impact scrolling rendering (the more subviews are shadowed the worse it is).

*Concerning rounded corners it may impact too (but less I think).*

The solution :

- **shadow** : from an **image** or place a **subview behind** to make a shadow like effect
- **rounded corner** : **image**

That is what I did, It was a bit a defeat not to be able to do like I wanted but result was OK.

Comment: Just a heads up for the future, you can do the rounded corners without `masksToBounds` which was the real culprit. Check out the link in my answer, you can do it without images.