# iOS UITableView scroll not smoothly after set the layer.cornerRadius of subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making a calendar view using `UITableView` (see image below), each `UITableViewCell` represent a month with several subviews and each subview means one day let's call it a `DayView`, every `DayView` contains a subview UILabel to show the day of the month. Until now, everything seems good, and the scrolling of `UITableView` is smoothly. But after I add this line in the `DayView`'s `- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

The UITableView's frame rate become much lower when scrolling. It can't catch up my finger at all. So what is the most likely cause?

By the way, what should I do to resolve this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Edit:

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *monthCellIdentifier = @"MonthCell";
    OPCalendarPageView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:monthCellIdentifier];
    cell.manager = _manager;
    cell.date = [self dateForIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

And I'm using the library [JTCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLQLJ.png), `OPCalendarPageView` is a custom version of `JTCalendarPageView`, just added a month label above the first day of month.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why do you need rounded corners for each day view?

Comment: please add the code for -cellForRowAtIndexpath:

Comment: @rmaddy I just wanted to make the shape of day view something other than a rectangle, then found this problem.

Comment: OK, but the image you show is white on white with no borders. How would it look any different with rounded corners on the days?

Comment: Well, I'd like to add more element to day view, such as different background color, event marker, etc. so they will be look different with rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please mention bit more , like scenario of your sub-views or  rather than setting corner radius  what other properties you have set like border-width or masktobound or cliptobound or etc.

secondly,
I am not sure but i had solved my issue with  setting just following line

`self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`

or if this solution does not work then try following link in which [fknrdcls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654635/fknrdcls) gave very good answer in proper way regarding to protect  corner radius negative impact on uitableview.
basically uitableview is subclass of uiscrollview so, below solution might be solve your problem.

> [UILabel layer cornerRadius negatively impacting performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance)

Comment: This really did the trick, amazing!